# ajax and php returns json exception

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to upload a file in my local webserver but I'm running into an error that I don't fully understand. I think there might be an issue with my PHP script.
Here is my code :

JS :

```
addImageBlobHook: (blob, callback) => {

            let formData = new FormData();

            // file in a 'multipart/form-data' request
            formData.append(0, blob, blob.name);

            fetch('upload', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            }).then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                }

                throw new Error('Server or network error');
            }).then(response => {
                if (!response.success) {
                    throw new Error('Validation error');
                }

                callback(response.data.url, 'alt text');
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
```

PHP :

```
    <?php
    
    if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){
        // file name
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    
        // Location
        $location = 'upload/'.$filename;
    
        // file extension
        $file_extension = pathinfo($location, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);
    
        // Valid extensions
        $valid_ext = array("jpg","png","jpeg");
    
        $response = 0;
        if(in_array($file_extension,$valid_ext)){
            // Upload file
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$location)){
                $response = 1;
            }
        }
    
        echo $response;
        exit;
    }

else echo json_encode(2);
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

on line 85, which is in my code the `console.log(error);` in the JS file.

**EDIT:**

Replacing isset($_FILES(['file.....) with just isset($_FILES) allow to enter the 'if' and make a vardump, like so :

```
if(isset($_FILES)){

    var_dump($_FILES);
```

Which returns :

```
C:\wamp64\www\toast\upload.php:5:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'Beer_mug_transparent.png' (length=24)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 3
      'size' => int 0
```

Comment: Check the raw response you're actually getting back from PHP. You can use the browser's network tool to examine the specific Ajax request and see the original response. Your response clearly contains content which cannot be interpreted as JSON

Comment: If the response is empty then that would cause the error. You need to return _something_ in all cases, even if it's an empty JSON array or object. The GET response is largely irrelevant since you're not using that in your Ajax. Also I noticed you aren't even attempting to encode any data you do return as JSON, so that needs sorting out too.

Comment: Is json_encode($response); enough to encode the returned data ?
I don't think the response is empty.
Chrome gives a better view of the error :
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
// i think it's because there is HTML in my response but I don't understand why

Comment: `Is json_encode($response); enough to encode the returned data`...yes, but also make sure your script doesn't output anything else (accidentally or on purpose) before that - the response tab in the network tool should show up any HTML or other extraneous content (even whitespace is bad).Or you could get HTML returned if PHP throws an error and you haven't trapped that. (Although in this particular case, you seem to be returning simply 0 or 1 so actually it's just a single simple number, so trying to encode and interpret that as JSON seems a bit pointless, your JS could just read the raw text.)

Comment: in my JS, I changed 'upload' to 'upload.php' (since its the name of my script, and upload is just a folder)
No more HTML is returned. But the original Json error is still here and upload still fails.
Can I trap PHP errors with a try catch?

Comment: just added an else statement at the end of my script. It always goes in the else and returns "validation error"

Comment: `Can I trap PHP errors with a try catch?`...yes, it's in the PHP manual.

Comment: `at the end of my script`...you mean after the outer `if` statement you've shown us? or one of the inner ones? Edit your question to show the exact change, please.

Comment: Edited. I removed isset($_FILES['files']['name'] and left just isset($_FILES). Now it goes in the if. Var_dump of $_FILES just returns a json array with the file name

Comment: var_dump doesn't return JSON, it uses its own output format. Edit again and show us the exact output of the var_dump please.

Comment: Done. It's not a blob image isn't it ? Nor is it a base64 one

Comment: Thanks. It's easier to see the issue now. So, clearly your $_FILES has no array element called "file". It has one called "0" - as per what you specified when you wrote `formData.append(0` in the javascript. The first argument to append is the parameter name (as per [the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append), therefore that's the name that PHP has to use to try and find the input when it receives the form submission. Therefore I'd expect `$_FILES[0]["name"]` to work.

Comment: And no you didn't upload base64 no, it's a normal multipart request with binary data in it (the fact it came from a blob generated by your JS application, or from a file input element is irrelevant, once it gets as far as PHP)

Comment: Brilliant ! It works fine now ! Thanks for helping and sorry for asking stupid questions

Comment: No problem. Just remember the parameter name you send needs to match the one your PHP is looking for. There's no magic, just simple string matching :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are just echo the response. Which does not give proper response. Please see updated php code.

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){
    // file name
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    // Location
    $location = 'upload/'.$filename;

    // file extension
    $file_extension = pathinfo($location, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);

    // Valid extensions
    $valid_ext = array("jpg","png","jpeg");

    $response = 0;
    if(in_array($file_extension,$valid_ext)){
        // Upload file
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$location)){
            $response = 1;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```